# Understanding recursive exponent programming with Java

Tags: java

I'm having difficulty understanding recursive programming. I would really like if someone could explain to me what happens in each "loop" of the sample code below, so I can understand what the recursion is doing.

Here´s the code:

```
public static int potenz2(int x, int n) {
        int ergebnis = 0;
        if(n == 0){ 
            ergebnis = 1;
        }else{
            ergebnis = x * potenz2(x, n-1);
        }
        System.out.println(ergebnis);

        return ergebnis; 

        }
```

Comment: This function multiplies a number by the result of next recursive call while second argument is not equal to zero.

Comment: What are you having trouble understanding exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is raising x to the power of n.

**Recursion means the function/method is directly or indirectly calling itself.** In your case the `potenz2()` method is calling itself directly.

The algorithm:

1. The way the algorithm works is by decrementing the 2nd argument, because:

   - `potenz2(10, 1)` = 10 (10 to the power of 1)
   - `potenz2(10, 2)` = 100 = 10 * `potenz(10, 1)`
   - `potenz2(10, 3)` = 1000 = 10 * `potenz(10, 2)` = 10 * 10 * `potenz(10, 1)`
2. Your program can be simplified:

   ```
   public static int potenz2(int x, int n) {
       if (n == 0) {
           return 1;
       } else {
           return x * potenz2(x, n - 1);
       }
   }
   ```
3. The ending condition is anything to the power of 0 is 1.

Comment: Thank you! .. I was having trouble understanding how the method is calling it self with in the method.. i thought the potenz2(x, n - 1) was "creating" a new instance of the method that would never end.

thank you again!